# WSO2 API Manager 2.0 separate Registry DB Issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When i configure new  datasources to manage registry or user management data following [Setting up Oracle](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Setting+up+Oracle), and then start API Manager, it report below error:

```
[2016-08-05 09:59:49,876] ERROR - TransactionManager Failed to start new registry transaction.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:458)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.beginTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:443)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.get(EmbeddedRegistry.java:505)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.get(CacheBackedRegistry.java:203)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.getInternal(UserRegistry.java:617)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$400(UserRegistry.java:61)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:597)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$5.run(UserRegistry.java:594)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.get(UserRegistry.java:594)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.AsyncIndexer$IndexingTask.createIndexDocument(AsyncIndexer.java:242)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.AsyncIndexer$IndexingTask.run(AsyncIndexer.java:210)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:392)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:434)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:687)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:363)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:150)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:370)
        ... 32 more
```

What's the reason? i can confirm the data source configure is ok, i can find result from reg db and per check/test the data source from carbon page, they are also ok.

Comment: If i open the remoteInstance config, then it can work, but i can't confirm it's ok or not.
     `<dbConfig name="sharedregistry">
  <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
 </dbConfig>
<remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9443/registry">
        <id>instanceid</id>
        <dbConfig>sharedregistry</dbConfig>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
  <cacheId>wso2carbon@jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB</cacheId>
    </remoteInstance>`

Comment: According my understanding, in my single instance installation, it should just use local registry store. So why need to config remote?

Comment: seems it's XE connection limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicated that you are having a connection issue to the DB.

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

So I suggest you double check your DB connection. First telnet to oracle and make sure you can successfully connect to DB.

```
telnet localhost 1521
```

Make sure your Firewalls are configured to allow connection  to the DB.

Comment: I have confirmed the datasource config is ok , i had foud records in the db after API Manager started, and i also can test it from carbon page. According my understanding, i just update the datasource of registry's local storage , and i did not use remote config yet according http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances/ and https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+the+Database

Comment: Can you add ur masterdatsource config and registry.xml configs.

Comment: seems it's XE connection limitation.